# Insert HTML inside link in a walker

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, functions, walker, categories

I've got a custom nav walker that (theoretically) pulls the featured image from the most recent post in a custom taxonomy, and displays the the image after the link in a `wp_list_categories`.

The problem is I need the image to display above the category name, within the link. I can't seem to figure out how to do this.

This is my custom walker:

```
class CategoryThumbnailWalker extends Walker_Category {
    function start_el(&$output, $category, $depth, $args) {
        parent::start_el(&$output, $category, $depth, $args);
        $posts = get_posts(array(
            "child_of"         => $category->term_id, // may need to be disabled; we'll see
            "post_type"        => "projects",
            "project-category" => $category->slug,
        ));
        if ($posts) {
            foreach ($posts as $post) {
                if (has_post_thumbnail($post->ID)) {
                    $output .= get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID, "gallery-small");

                } else {
                    $output .= "<img alt=\"No image available\" src=\"" . get_template_directory_uri() . "/img/no-image.jpg\" />";
                }
                break;
            }
        } else {
            $output .= "<img alt=\"No image available\" src=\"" . get_template_directory_uri() . "/img/no-image.jpg\" />";
        }
    }
}
```

and here's my `wp_list_categories`:

```
$category = $wp_query->get_queried_object_id();
wp_list_categories(array(
    "child_of"         => $category,
    "depth"            => 1,
    "hide_empty"       => false,
    "hierarchical"     => 1,
    "orderby"          => "name",
    "pad_counts"       => 0,
    "post_type"        => "projects",
    "show_count"       => 0,
    "show_option_none" => "",
    "taxonomy"         => "project-category",
    "title_li"         => "",
    "walker"           => new CategoryThumbnailWalker()
));
```

And here's what it all outputs:

```
<li class="cat-item cat-item-13">
    <a href="http://christopherconsultants.myweblinx.net/project-category/education/" title="View all posts filed under Education">
        Education
    </a>
    <img alt="No image available" src="http://christopherconsultants.myweblinx.net/wp-content/themes/christopher-consultants/img/no-image.jpg">
</li>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to skip the `CategoryThumbnailWalker` and use instead the `list_cats` filter.

Here's an untested example:

```
add_filter( 'list_cats', 'wpse_149898_list_cats', 99, 2 );

wp_list_categories(array(
    "child_of"         => get_queried_object_id(),
    "depth"            => 1,
    "hide_empty"       => false,
    "hierarchical"     => 1,
    "orderby"          => "name",
    "pad_counts"       => 0,
    "post_type"        => "projects",
    "show_count"       => 0,
    "show_option_none" => "",
    "taxonomy"         => "project-category",
    "title_li"         => "",
));

remove_filter( 'list_cats', 'wpse_149898_list_cats', 99, 2 );
```

where

```
/**
 * Prepend the featured image, from the most recent project 
 * in a custom taxonomy, to the term name.
 *
 * @param string $cat_name
 * @param object $category
 * @return string 
 */    

function wpse_149898_list_cats(  $cat_name, $category )
{   
    $posts = get_posts( array(
        'post_type'        => 'projects',
        'posts_per_page'   => 1,
        'meta_key'         =>'_thumbnail_id',
        'project-category' => $category->slug,
    ) );

    $img = sprintf( "<img alt=\"No image available\" src=\"%s/img/no-image.jpg\" />",
        get_template_directory_uri()
    );

    if ( $posts ):
        foreach ( $posts as $post )
        {
            if ( has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ) )
                $img = get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, 'gallery-small' );

        }
    endif;    
    return $img . $cat_name;
}
```

The output should (hopefully) be like this:

```
<li class="cat-item cat-item-13">
    <a href="http://christopherconsultants.myweblinx.net/project-category/education/" title="View all posts filed under Education">
        <img alt="No image available" src="http://christopherconsultants.myweblinx.net/wp-content/themes/christopher-consultants/img/no-image.jpg">
        Education
    </a>
</li>
```

Comment: This is close, but for some reason this isn't working in every case. If you look at http://christopherconsultants.myweblinx.net/projects/ you'll see On the Boards has an image, but Public Sector doesn't. These both should have featured images. I'm not sure what's going on.

Comment: Ah, it appears it's not querying deeper level categories for posts...I'm not sure if it should work like that or not... Hmm. I'll look in to it more, thanks for the help.

Comment: ok hopefully you can adjust the leveling but it looks like you're using HTML tags in your term descriptions. You can see it in the link title attributes.

Comment: I updated the answer, to fetch only projects with featured images. Hopefully this helps. You might also consider random ordering instead of the default date descending order.